# Not able to select multiple files using UIDocumentPickerViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uidocumentpickervc

I'm trying to import/pick multiple files at once from files app using `UIDocumentPickerViewController`. 
 Tried setting `allowsMultipleSelection = true` but still there is no "**Select**" option while picker is presented.

Code snippet :

```
UIDocumentPickerViewController *dvc = [[UIDocumentPickerViewController alloc]initWithDocumentTypes:arrContents inMode:UIDocumentPickerModeImport];
dvc.delegate = self;
dvc.allowsMultipleSelection = true;
[self presentViewController:dvc animated:true completion:nil];
```

Screenshot :
[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a bug Apple needs to fix. You can use this workaround. If you set `animated:` to `YES`, it will only work the first time you show the document picker.

**Objective-C:**

```
[self presentViewController:dvc animated:NO completion:^{
    if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
        dvc.allowsMultipleSelection = YES;
    }
}];
```

**Swift 4:**

```
self.present(dvc, animated: false) {
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        dvc.allowsMultipleSelection = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sometimes you need to switch between "Recents" and "Browse" before the "Select" button becomes visible on iPad. If you present the document picker as form sheet, it should be visible right away.

Comment: But this really needs to be fixed by Apple. I already filed a radar. You should, too!

Comment: Make sure to use `documentPicker:didPickDocumentsAtURLs:` instead of `documentPicker:didPickDocumentAtURL:`.

Comment: How is this still not fixed on iOS 14!? Also, the answer doesn't seem to work on iOS 14...

Comment: Turns out it's a behaviour change. Please refer to the "iOS" section, here: https://github.com/DelphiWorlds/Kastri/blob/master/Demos/FilesSelector/ReadMe.md